# How to specify sub-dependency for AutoWired Beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-bean

I have a Spring component defined like this:

```java
@Component
public class SearchIndexImpl implements SearchIndex {
    IndexUpdater indexUpdater;

    @Autowired
    public SearchIndexImpl(final IndexUpdater indexUpdater) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(indexUpdater);
        this.indexUpdater = indexUpdater;
    }
}
```

along with two implementations of the `IndexUpdater` interface, like:

```
@Component
public class IndexDirectUpdater implements IndexUpdater, DisposableBean, InitializingBean {

}

@Component
public class IndexQueueUpdater implements IndexUpdater, DisposableBean, InitializingBean {
}
```

If I try to auto-wire `SearchIndexImpl` like this:

```
@Autowired
private SearchIndex searchIndex;
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'IndexUpdater' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: indexDirectUpdater,indexQueueUpdater
```

which is expected since Spring cannot tell which `IndexUpdater` implementation to auto-wire for the `indexUpdater` parameter in the constructor of `SearchIndexImpl`. How do I guide Spring to the bean that it should use? I understand I can use the `@Qualifier` annotation, but that will hard-code the index updater to one of the implementation, while I want the user to be able to specify what index updater to use. In XML, I can do something like:

```
<bean id="searchIndexWithDirectUpdater" class="SearchIndexImpl"> 
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="indexDirectUpdater"/>
</bean>
```

How do I do the same using Spring's Java annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@Qualifier` annotation to specify the dependency to use :

```
public SearchIndexImpl(@Qualifier("indexDirectUpdater") IndexUpdater indexUpdater) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(indexUpdater);
    this.indexUpdater = indexUpdater;
}
```

Note that `@Autowired` is not needed to autowire the arg constructor of a bean since Spring 4.

---

**To answer to your comment.**

To let the class that will use the bean to define the dependency to use you could allow it to define the `IndexUpdater` instance to inject in the container such as :

```
// @Component not required any longer
public class IndexDirectUpdater implements IndexUpdater, DisposableBean, InitializingBean {

}

// @Component not required any longer
public class IndexQueueUpdater implements IndexUpdater, DisposableBean, InitializingBean {
}
```

Declare the bean in a @Configuration class :

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration{

@Bean
public IndexUpdater getIndexUpdater(){
     return new IndexDirectUpdater();
}
```

The `SearchIndexImpl` bean will now resolve the dependency thanks to  `IndexUpdater getIndexUpdater()`.
Here we use `@Component` for one bean and `@Bean` for its dependency.
But we could also allow a full control on the beans to instantiate by using only `@Bean` and by removing `@Component` on the 3 classes :

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration{

@Bean
public IndexUpdater getIndexUpdater(){
     return new IndexDirectUpdater();
}

@Bean 
public SearchIndexImpl getSearchIndexFoo(){
     return new SearchIndexImpl(getIndexUpdater());
}
```

Comment: The @Qualifier hard-code the `IndexUpdater` to use. In this case, it will always be the direct updater. I want whoever wants to use that class to decide which one index updater to use.

Comment: You cannot because the bean is set at the Spring startup and dependencies are not designed to be changed according to the client that manipulates it.   The better approach to do that would be to autowire both dependencies in the `SearchIndexImpl()` and to use the one or the second one according to a client parameter. Other alternative : allowing the client to pass the instance of IndexUpdater as it invokes methods on  `SearchIndexImplBean`. May make sense in some cases.

Comment: I see. But in XML definitions, it is possible to do something like:

```
    <bean id="searchIndexWithDirectUpdater" class="SearchIndexImpl">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="indexDirectUpdater"/>
```

Is there no equivalent to this using Java annotations?

Comment: The XML is not easy to read in the comment, so I updated my question.

Comment: I added some alternative to set the dependency outside the component.

Comment: Thanks. I did actually eventually did what you suggested, but it is good to get a confirmation that I am on the right track.